# How do you use a class from a different file?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use a class from a different file.

something.rb

```
class Something
  def initialize
  end
  def getText
    'Some example text'
  end
end
```

another.rb

```
class Another
end

somethingVar = Something.new
puts somethingVar.getText
```

This gives me the error

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/chris/RubymineProjects/untitled1/another.rb
/home/chris/RubymineProjects/untitled1/another.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Something (NameError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it rails project? If not, you have to require the file containing the definition before you can use it.

Comment: @Chris, if you feel the question has been answered, it's a good idea to mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to use code like this is via [require](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require):

```
require 'something.rb'
```

..will enable the use of classes defined within that file, but only if the file can be found either in the Ruby loadpath, or associated with an installed gem.

If you want to write your own, especially for testing or short-term hacking, you'll probably want to use [require_relative](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative), which takes a relative path to the file you want to use:

```
require_relative './something.rb'`
```

That should work if something.rb is in the same directory as another.rb

More info on various ways to reuse code in Ruby can be found [here](https://practicingruby.com/articles/ways-to-load-code).

Comment: To nitpick myself, 'require' will also work if you give it an absolute path from the root of the filesystem.  But read the last link there for a truly complete understanding.

Comment: You don't need (and it is normal practice  to omit ) the extension in calls to require / require_relative

Comment: That has been my experience as well, @FrederickCheung, and I agree.  In this case, however, I included the extension in the hope of avoiding confusion for a newer user, and to make it clear that it's a file path and not a class name.

Answer (score 5):

You have to require the something.rb.

```
require 'something.rb'
```

Comment: Initially I thought that but if I put that at the top of another.rb I get the following error:

in `require': cannot load such file -- something (LoadError)

Comment: Try `require './something'`.

Comment: That won't work, as `.` (the current dir) is not in `$LOAD_PATH`. `require_relative` is the way to go.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if the current dir is in the $LOAD_PATH. `require './something'` will work.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: It is extremely common to see the file name required WITHOUT the `.rb` extension, as shown in the examples below.

As others have stated, you must require 'something' if in the same load path.

```
require 'something'
```

or require_relative './something', by including the path to the file.

```
require_relative 'something'
```

"Aside from looking nicer, this bareword way of referring to the extension is necessary because not all extensions use files ending in .rb. Specifically, extensions written in C are stored in files ending with .so or .dll. To keep the process transparent-that is, to save you the trouble of knowing whether the extension you want uses a .rb file or not-Ruby accepts a bareword and then does some automatic file-searching and trying out of possible filenames until it finds the file corresponding to the extension you have requested."

For more info - http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html